# How to move a directory?

Tags: filesystems, directory, mv, hadoop, distributed-filesystem

I have a directory in HDFS with subdirectories that contain part-xxxxx files, created by Spark. I want to move that directory (and everything inside it) into a new directory. How to?

---

My attempt:

```
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -mv  /projects/landmarks/ /projects/landmarks/all/
mv: ` /projects/landmarks/': No such file or directory
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -mv  /projects/landmarks/* /projects/landmarks/all/
mv: ` /projects/landmarks/*': No such file or directory
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -mv  /projects/landmarks/*/* /projects/landmarks/all/
mv: ` /projects/landmarks/*/*': No such file or directory
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /projects/landmarks/
Found 116 items
drwx------   - gsamaras edugr          0 2016-09-07 18:08 /projects/landmarks/Parthenon
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ mv projects/landmarks/ projects/landmarks/all/` 
*mv: rename projects/landmarks/ to projects/landmarks/all/landmarks/:
 Invalid argument*
You can not move the **Main Directory** into one of its **Subdirectories**. 

**Directory & Contents**
`mv /projects/landmarks /projects/landmarks/all`

**Contents Within Directory**
`mv /projects/landmarks/* /projects/landmarks/all`

Is your desired path `projects/landmarks` at user or root?
Adding the initial slash is pointing bash to look @ root level for your directory.
**With Initial "/" it will point to Root** 
*/Users/Foo/projects/landmarks/all* 
**Without Initial "/" it will point to your current working directory**
*projects/landmarks/all*

Comment: I am trying to understand how is this different from my attempt... :/ It looks the same!

Comment: There you go, just edited it. Seems like an error in your path. Is /projects/ at root or user level?

Comment: Thanks for the updated. *Unfortunately* both approaches raise the same error as in my attempt. The path is somewhere in HDFS.

Comment: I replicated what you did and got: mv: rename projects/landmarks/ to projects/landmarks/all/landmarks/: Invalid argument. Its because you can not move **directory1** to **directory2** within **directory1**